# How to return Future as json?

Tags: json, scala, asynchronous, playframework

I receive error while trying to return action that returns Future of Object as json. My Method looks like that:

```
  def register: Action[JsValue] = Action.async(parse.json) {
    implicit request: Request[JsValue] => {
      val registerCredentials: RegisterDto = request.body.as[RegisterDto]
      if (registerCredentials.password != registerCredentials.repeatPassword) {
        NotAcceptable("Passwords don't match")
      }
      Try.apply(registerService.createUser(registerCredentials.email, registerCredentials.password))
        .map(user => Ok(Json.toJson(user)))
        .orElse(InternalServerError(s"Error creating new user") )
    }
```

Register service

```
registerService.createUser(registerCredentials.email, registerCredentials.password)
```

Returns Future of user and I would like to return it from my controller, as database execution is async using Slick.

After trying too start the server I receive following error:

```
No Json serializer found for type scala.concurrent.Future[login.register.dao.user.User]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
[error]         .map(user => Ok(Json.toJson(user)))
```

My User class has a implicit mapper:

```
case class User(id: Long, email: String, password: String, isActive: Boolean)

object User {
  implicit val personFormat = Json.format[User]
}
```

I believe there is a problem with returning it as a future and then Json. But It worked for me in another endpoint where I didn't have to use `Action.async(parse.json)`, just `Action.async`

I am looking for solution to read Json from request and then return some Future of object as json.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I can't map Future to json, but I can map Future so the result is mapped to json. The result should look like:

```
      Try.apply(registerService.createUser(registerCredentials.email, registerCredentials.password))
        .map(future => future.map(user => Ok(Json.toJson(user))))
        .getOrElse(Future(InternalServerError("Error creating new user")))
```

I am not sure if it's proper way, if I am wrong please correct me

Comment: That's overcomplicated (and somewhat wrong), just `createUser(..).map(Json.toJson(_))`